# How to Create Unique Constraint with Multiple Columns using ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

How does one create a unique constraint with ServiceStack.OrmLite (using attributes, hopefully)?  The documentation shows how to create a unique constraint only on a single column:

[ServiceStack.OrmLite Docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite)

If it helps, I am using `ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service Stack appears to have a CompositeIndex attribute which takes multiple field names.  Here's a look at the constructors...

```
CompositeIndexAttribute(params string[] fieldNames);
CompositeIndexAttribute(bool unique, params string[] fieldNames);
```

Comment: Added this to the class.  Worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, prior to v4.0.12 (March 2014), it was only possible to add one composite index.  Be sure to update your build if you need multiple on a single table.