# Servicestack Ormlite multi-column constraint fails where constraint includes Enum

Tags: enums, servicestack, multiple-columns, unique-constraint, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack.Ormlite, and also make heavy use of the automatic handling of enums whereby they are stored in the db as strings but retrieved and parsed nicely back into Enums on retrieval, so I can do easy type-comparison - say, for a property "UserRole" in the db/table class "User" of enum type "UserRoleEnum" (just for demonstration).

This works great.. until I want to use the enum property to define a multi-column unique constraint

```
CompositeIndexAttribute(bool unique, params string[] fieldNames);
```

like:

```
[CompositeIndex(true, nameof(UserId), nameof(UserRole)]
public class User 
{ 
    public long UserId {get;set;} 
    public UserRoleEnum UserRole {get;set; 
}
```

(as per :
[How to Create Unique Constraint with Multiple Columns using ServiceStack.OrmLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802023/how-to-create-unique-constraint-with-multiple-columns-using-servicestack-ormlite/21804378#21804378) ).

At which time i get:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Column 'UserRole' in table 'User' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
```

I currently see options as:

a) Define UserRole as a string (isntead of UserRoleEnum ) in the table entity class and lose the Enum use.... having to manually test the value each time to confirm that the db value is one that i expect in my business logic later

b) Continue to use UserRoleEnum but lose the ability to declare multicolumn uniqueconstraints using the class attribute, and probably have to create these manually using a subsequent db migration script?

Is there any way to make the enums and the multicolumn constraint play nicely, out of the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was because `enum` properties were using the default string definition fallback of `VARCHAR(MAX)` which SQL Server doesn't let you create indexes on whereas the column definition of a `string` property is `VARCHAR(8000)`.

This issue is now resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/9373ef26d8a34941beedddceedf24a9f3933e3bf) which now uses the `VARCHAR(255)` string definition of the `EnumConverter` Type Converter. This change is available from v4.5.5 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Otherwise you can also change the size of the column definition to match a `string` property by adding a `[StringLength]` attribute, e.g:

```
[CompositeIndex(true, nameof(UserId), nameof(UserRole))]
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(8000)]
    public string UserRole { get; set; }
}
```